# How to remove the fluctuation from the main navigation submenu links

Tags: html, css

I create the main navigation in and its submenus, in 
`<header> </header>` tag and make the header position fixed.
when i hover over the sublist items these are fluctuating can any one tell me what is the reason.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's difficult to say.. can you show how fluctuating is.

Comment: Can you provide any fiddle for the same

Comment: At **StackOverflow** we do not provide *coding services*. We are here to help, so before asking any questions here please take a [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of *SO* and study [**how to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [**create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is the website link plz check it out http://epatronus.com/